# How does community libraries by-pass framework limitations?

Tags: android, animation, frameworks, release, libraries

I have come across this non-framework library **com.nineoldandroids.animation** 
which is exactly like the framework library **android.view.animation**

**android.view.animation** framework library was introduced in Honeycomb.
So good people created **com.nineoldandroids.animation** for all the releases prior to honeycomb (all the way back to API 1.0)

My question is how does this non-framework library able to pull off framework stunts?
Aren't we all limited to what the framework is able to do and the API's that is exposes?
Isn't the framework acting like a wall between our app (and community libraries) and the hardware?
Isn't everything that an app can do is basically use the framework API ?
how does this **com.nineoldandroids.animation**  library doing stuff that the the old framework \ OS can't?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NineOldAndroids library isn't doing anything that's limited to the system framework. The entire Android code base is open source and the NineOldAndroids library simply mirrors the newly introduced animation classes.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?
From what i know, every method in the API invokes a method in deeper layer in the library, which in turn invokes methods in the OS, which in turn invokes the hardware.

Comment: Doesn't NineOldAndroids MUST HAVE certain permission in order to do what the framework does?

Comment: No, you're confusing system-level protected methods, such as `powerOffDevice();`, which can only be called by apps that are signed with the system-key with regular methods that are built into the Android system. Yes, the animation methods are part of the framework API, but there's nothing stopping anyone from taking them out of the open source repository and compiling them into a library or a standalone app.